# Duplicate a SVG's tree

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I want to Duplicate my tree, i tried to create a new variable, where i putted the querySelector("svg") of the tree, and after that, append it to the parentNode, but it doesn't work actually, how can i do it ?

This is the function where i tried to do the duplication :

```
function add_total_svg(svg, globaldiv, cell) {
    var last_svg = document.querySelector("svg");
    cell = globaldiv.append("div").attr("class", "total");
    cell.append("p").text("Total").attr("style", "font-family: Helvetica");
    cell.append(last_svg); //The duplication fail here
}
```

Here is the code + visualization :

https://plnkr.co/edit/drxD4LLmfiqD6B0iM8wn?p=preview

Thanks you again <3

Comment: You can use [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode): `cell.append(() => last_svg.cloneNode(true));`.

Comment: But make sure you do .cloneNode(true) if you need deep copy

Comment: Amazing, it worked, but just a question, what does it mean the "() =>" at the start of the append ?? @altocumulus

Comment: @zahreddine That's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) introduced to JavaScript with ES6. Have a look at the documentation on [`selection.append()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_append): if you want to append a node, you have to return it from a function; you cannot just do `.append(last_svg.cloneNode(true))`. In pre-ES6 syntax this would be `cell.append(function() { return last_svg.cloneNode(true); })`.